# .htaccess query string and redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a **.htaccess** :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.css|\.js|\.png)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?v=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /src/html/404.php
```

And in my **index.php** I get the '**v**' variable and check if the page exist in the database.

If the page exist, I will include the content of the page and if the page doesn't exist, I will include the 404 error page.

Everything work without any problem, except when I try to access an existing directory like :

*example.com/src*

It will automatically redirect to :

*example.com/src/?v=src*

And show the error page

But when I try with :

*example.com/src/* (with '**/**' at the end of the URL)

It will keep the URL and show the error page ! (This is what I need)

Now I would like to know how can I achieve the same result when the URL end without '**/**' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tricky solution, but I don't know if it's a good idea or not !

I edited my *.htaccess* file and added :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```

This works fine, except it will add a "**/**" to the end of the URL (It's not a problem, but change the URL which I don't like)

**Update**

I found the correct solution :

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Answer (score 0):

add 2 lines for checking the url is not a really exists file or folder

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.css|\.js|\.png)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?v=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: This will make it worst ! it will list the directories !